# Installing Python 3.4 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, python, apt, update

Is it possible to run python 3.4 on a Raspberry Pi?

Currently I have python 3.2, but the odd thing is that running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3
```

results in my Raspberry Pi informing me that `python3` is 'already the newest version'.

I have also tried `sudo apt-get install python34`, but this tells me that no such package exists.

Does anyone know how to get python 3.4 running on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: It is available on raspbian jessie, just not on wheezy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems Python 3.4 is still in beta, and there is no package prepared for it yet. If youstill want python 3.4, you should download it and build it from source.

You can find it here: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-340/ Download the source tar ball. The build instructions should be in there.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am trying it now. The python blog it says that python 3.4 has been released, so how can it still be in beta?

Comment: Yep, This worked. Thank you! Accepted as the answer. A word of warning to other users: It took a _long_ time to compile - make sure you have a couple of hours to spare before attempting.

Comment: Great! Good luck!

Comment: starbeamrainbowlabs, Python 3.4 (the python language) is released (from the Python Software Foundation) as you say.  The Python34 Debian package that corresponds to Python 3.4 is still in beta, however.  After the PSF releases a new version of the language, folks on the Debian team still want to vet that version with the rest of the Debian software ecosystem and so the Debian package is still considered "beta".

Comment: Well, no longer in beta!

Answer (score 4):

I have written a short tutorial on how to achieve this. You can find it here : http://depado.markdownblog.com/2015-03-12-short-tutorial-raspbian-python3-4-rpi-gpio

The above answer is right, you need to compile Python 3.4/3.5 from source and install a few system libs before you do that to have a fully functionnal Python installation. Also you'll need to install the RPi.GPIO from pip if you want to use the GPIO on your Raspberry.

You also need to have some free time to do that because compiling Python can take up to one hour on Raspberry.

Hope that helps even if the question has already been answered.

Answer (score -2):

I used:

```
conda create -n py3k python=3.4 anaconda
```

Provided the following out of the box on my Pi2, many of which are normally a nightmare to get working on python.

```
package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
abstract-rendering-0.5.1   |       np19py34_0          68 KB
anaconda-2.2.0             |       np19py34_0           3 KB
argcomplete-0.8.4          |           py34_0          29 KB
astropy-1.0.1              |       np19py34_0         7.2 MB
bcolz-0.8.1                |       np19py34_0         1.1 MB
beautiful-soup-4.3.2       |           py34_0         114 KB
binstar-0.10.1             |           py34_3          74 KB
bitarray-0.8.1             |           py34_0          90 KB
blaze-core-0.7.3           |       np19py34_0         313 KB
blz-0.6.2                  |       np19py34_0        1009 KB
bokeh-0.8.1                |       np19py34_1        13.5 MB
boto-2.36.0                |           py34_0         1.4 MB
certifi-14.05.14           |           py34_0         154 KB
cffi-0.9.2                 |           py34_0         186 KB
clyent-0.3.4               |           py34_0          13 KB
colorama-0.3.3             |           py34_0          18 KB
configobj-5.0.6            |           py34_0          51 KB
cryptography-0.8           |           py34_0         690 KB
curl-7.38.0                |                0         495 KB
cython-0.22                |           py34_0         5.8 MB
cytoolz-0.7.2              |           py34_0         718 KB
datashape-0.4.4            |       np19py34_1          99 KB
decorator-3.4.0            |           py34_0           5 KB
docutils-0.12              |           py34_0         672 KB
dynd-python-0.6.5          |       np19py34_0         2.1 MB
fastcache-1.0.2            |           py34_0          41 KB
flask-0.10.1               |           py34_1         135 KB
fontconfig-2.11.1          |                2         382 KB
freetype-2.5.2             |                0         2.4 MB
greenlet-0.4.5             |           py34_0          35 KB
h5py-2.4.0                 |       np19py34_0         2.6 MB
hdf5-1.8.14                |                0         1.5 MB
ipython-3.0.0              |           py34_0         3.4 MB
ipython-notebook-3.0.0     |           py34_1           5 KB
ipython-qtconsole-3.0.0    |           py34_0           4 KB
itsdangerous-0.24          |           py34_0          16 KB
jdcal-1.0                  |           py34_0           9 KB
jedi-0.8.1                 |           py34_0         176 KB
jinja2-2.7.3               |           py34_1         351 KB
jpeg-8d                    |                0         663 KB
jsonschema-2.4.0           |           py34_0          53 KB
libdynd-0.6.5              |                0        16.4 MB
libffi-3.0.13              |                0          29 KB
libpng-1.5.13              |                1         142 KB
libsodium-0.4.5            |                0         582 KB
libtiff-4.0.2              |                1         836 KB
libxml2-2.9.0              |                0         3.7 MB
libxslt-1.1.28             |                0         1.0 MB
llvmlite-0.2.2             |           py34_1         7.5 MB
lxml-3.4.2                 |           py34_0         3.1 MB
markupsafe-0.23            |           py34_0          31 KB
matplotlib-1.4.3           |       np19py34_1        44.8 MB
mistune-0.5.1              |           py34_0          10 KB
mock-1.0.1                 |           py34_0          37 KB
multipledispatch-0.4.7     |           py34_0          12 KB
networkx-1.9.1             |           py34_0         977 KB
nltk-3.0.2                 |       np19py34_0         1.6 MB
nose-1.3.4                 |           py34_1         195 KB
numba-0.17.0               |       np19py34_0         966 KB
numexpr-2.3.1              |       np19py34_0         330 KB
numpy-1.9.2                |           py34_0         6.7 MB
odo-0.3.1                  |       np19py34_0         141 KB
openpyxl-1.8.5             |           py34_0         131 KB
openssl-1.0.1k             |                1         2.4 MB
pandas-0.15.2              |       np19py34_1        10.8 MB
patsy-0.3.0                |       np19py34_0         355 KB
pep8-1.6.2                 |           py34_0          27 KB
pillow-2.7.0               |           py34_1         744 KB
pip-6.0.8                  |           py34_0         1.6 MB
ply-3.4                    |           py34_0          69 KB
psutil-2.2.1               |           py34_0         101 KB
ptyprocess-0.4             |           py34_0          19 KB
py-1.4.26                  |           py34_0         126 KB
pyasn1-0.1.7               |           py34_0          51 KB
pycosat-0.6.1              |           py34_0         144 KB
pycparser-2.10             |           py34_0         148 KB
pycrypto-2.6.1             |           py34_0         469 KB
pycurl-7.19.5.1            |           py34_0         106 KB
pyflakes-0.8.1             |           py34_0          53 KB
pygments-2.0.2             |           py34_0         1.1 MB
pyopenssl-0.14             |           py34_0         127 KB
pyparsing-2.0.3            |           py34_0          66 KB
pyqt-4.11.3                |           py34_0         3.1 MB
pytables-3.1.1             |       np19py34_2         3.3 MB
pytest-2.6.4               |           py34_0         184 KB
python-3.4.3               |                0        22.5 MB
python-dateutil-2.4.1      |           py34_0         219 KB
pytz-2015.2                |           py34_0         175 KB
pyyaml-3.11                |           py34_0         348 KB
pyzmq-14.5.0               |           py34_0         702 KB
qt-4.8.6                   |                0        35.3 MB
readline-6.2               |                2         552 KB
requests-2.6.0             |           py34_0         622 KB
rope-0.9.4                 |           py34_1         239 KB
runipy-0.1.3               |           py34_0           9 KB
scikit-image-0.11.2        |       np19py34_0        23.7 MB
scikit-learn-0.15.2        |       np19py34_0         7.3 MB
scipy-0.15.1               |       np19py34_0        31.4 MB
setuptools-14.3            |           py34_0         440 KB
sip-4.16.5                 |           py34_0         201 KB
six-1.9.0                  |           py34_0          17 KB
sockjs-tornado-1.0.1       |           py34_0          32 KB
sphinx-1.2.3               |           py34_0        1015 KB
spyder-2.3.4               |           py34_1         4.0 MB
spyder-app-2.3.4           |           py34_0           8 KB
sqlalchemy-0.9.9           |           py34_0         1.3 MB
sqlite-3.8.4.1             |                1         2.5 MB
statsmodels-0.6.1          |       np19py34_0         5.2 MB
sympy-0.7.6                |           py34_0         6.5 MB
system-5.8                 |                2         156 KB
terminado-0.5              |           py34_0          18 KB
tk-8.5.18                  |                0         1.8 MB
toolz-0.7.1                |           py34_0          28 KB
tornado-4.1                |           py34_0         519 KB
ujson-1.33                 |           py34_0          48 KB
util-linux-2.21            |                0          35 KB
werkzeug-0.10.1            |           py34_0         403 KB
xlrd-0.9.3                 |           py34_0         163 KB
xlsxwriter-0.6.7           |           py34_0         177 KB
xz-5.0.5                   |                0         502 KB
zeromq-4.0.4               |                0         2.3 MB
zlib-1.2.8                 |                0         108 KB
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:       312.4 MB
```

Comment: You linked to this question?